# Trouble installing pthreads on M1, throwing error: fatal error: 'Zend/zend_ts_hash.h' file not found

Tags: php, macos, pthreads, apple-m1, phpbrew

I'm trying to install pthreads on my M1 using pecl but it throws an error:

```
 .phpbrew/build/php-8.1.6/ext/pthreads/php_pthreads.c:22:
 ./src/pthreads.h:59:10: fatal error: 'Zend/zend_ts_hash.h' file not
 found
 #include <Zend/zend_ts_hash.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 219 warnings and 1 error generated. make: *** [php_pthreads.lo] Error 1
```

Here are my current machine info:

- Monterey OS running on M1 machine
- PHP 7.4 (system installed)
- Installed PHP 8.1.6 via phpbrew
- PEAR Version: 1.10.13

Output of `php -v`:

```
PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 30 2022 23:27:18) (ZTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.1.6
Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

We have no idea what really is happening, but I'm assuming that the missing import should be part of the Zend Engine, right? I'm not sure if I messed up the PHP installation because I installed PHP from source and then use phpbrew for PHP installation.

Please let me know if you need more info. Thank you in advance